# Reduce steps in this simple maze puzzle?

Tags: python

[image: Puzzle]

[Video Puzzle](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qHYH2TQX8uu7psxm4bA6qsfcpWr_K5sG/view?usp=share_link)

Current code:

```
for i in range(6,0,-2):
    Spaceship.step(2)
    Dev.step(i)
    for idk in range(3):
        Dev.turnRight()
        Dev.step(i*2)
    Dev.turnRight()
    Dev.step(i)
```

In this puzzle the objective is to get all the item (blue thing). With 6 line of code, and I'm currently at 8 line of code. I don't know how to minimalize the line of code.

Note:
Dev.step() is the robot, it can go backward by set the value by negative.
Spaceship.step() is the spaceship, it can not go backward.

Comment: Do you understand what the hint is trying to say?

Comment: From the hint of the puzzle it says "Observe the collection route of Dev, apply the nested loop structure, and complete the challenge". I already tried it with my current code but, from the puzzle to get full score it only contains 6 line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid pythonesque code like so:

```py
for i in range(6,0,-2):
    Spaceship.step(2)
    for idk in range(4):
        Dev.step(i)
        Dev.turnRight()
        Dev.step(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution in only 6 lines:

```py
for i in range(6, 0, -2):
    Spaceship.step(2)
    for k, j in enumerate([1, 2, 2, 2, 1]):
        Dev.step(i * j)
        if k != 4:
            Dev.turnRight()
```

The idea is to group all steps of the robot in a list in order to do a **nested loop** and turn only if it is not the last element of the list.

Comment: What does the "k" or  "if k != 4: " means?

Comment: The `enumerate` function returns a tuple `(index, value)`. So, `k` is the index of the value `j` in the list and `if k != 4` checks that it is not the last item of the list.